# How to sort string index of php array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am interested to sort php array index key in ascending order,

I have this array

```
 (
[462 1 5.300] => 1
[462 9 4.900] => 1
[462 9 4.300] => 1
[462 2 4.800] => 1
[462 6 4.700] => 1
[462 7 4.900] => 1
[462 7 4.700] => 1
[462 8 4.500] => 1
[462 3 4.500] => 1
[462 4 4.700] => 1
[462 3 4.700] => 1
[462 5 4.500] => 1
)
```

I expect output to be like this after sort

```
(
[462 1 5.300] => 1
[462 2 4.800] => 1
[462 3 4.500] => 1
[462 3 4.700] => 1
[462 4 4.700] => 1
[462 5 4.500] => 1
[462 6 4.700] => 1
[462 7 4.700] => 1
[462 7 4.900] => 1
[462 8 4.500] => 1
[462 9 4.300] => 1
[462 9 4.900] => 1
)
```

I want to sort first 3 index which is used as string is it possible ? I have 3 more column in array but I am showing only 3 columns here..

Comment: So what code did you write for that.? Post your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A normal [`ksort()`](http://php.net/ksort) can do the trick, but if the sorting is to be performed in multiple orders (different orders for different parameter values), this wouldn't work.

You can achieve this with [`array_multisort()`](http://php.net/array_multisort). First you create three (or more, depending on the number of parameters you have) arrays - each containing the parameter values. Then simply pass it to `array_multisort()` with the corresponding sort flag:

```
$param1 = $param2 = $param3 = array();

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $parts = explode(' ', $key);
    $param1[] = $parts[0];
    $param2[] = $parts[1];
    $param3[] = $parts[2];
}

array_multisort($data, $param1, SORT_ASC, $param2, SORT_ASC, $param3, SORT_ASC);
```

If you want the sorting to be performed in descending order, then you can use `SORT_DESC` instead. See the documentation for a list of available sort flags.

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/123661)

Comment: +1 your demo is really helpful for newbie like me, Thanks a lot I am accepting and its easy to understand even

Answer (score 2):

The function `usort()` would be the answer, but you need to sort by key, not by value. So you'd have to use [`uksort()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php).

Tiny help for you (*not tested*):

```
<?php
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    $aParts = explode(' ',$a);
    $bParts = explode(' ',$b);
    if($aParts[0] !== $bParts[0]) {
      return ($aParts[0] >= $bParts[0]) ? -1 : 1;
    }
    if( (int) $aParts[1] !== (int) $bParts[1]) { // compare second parts as integer
      return ($aParts[1] >= $bParts[1]) ? -1 : 1;
    }
    if( (float) $aParts[2] !== (float) $bParts[2]) {
      return ($aParts[2] >= $bParts[2]) ? -1 : 1;        
    }
    return 0;
}

$a = array(
[462 1 5.300] => 1
[462 9 4.900] => 1
[462 9 4.300] => 1
[462 2 4.800] => 1
[462 6 4.700] => 1
[462 7 4.900] => 1
[462 7 4.700] => 1
[462 8 4.500] => 1
[462 3 4.500] => 1
[462 4 4.700] => 1
[462 3 4.700] => 1
[462 5 4.500] => 1
);

uksort($a, "cmp");

foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key: $value\n";
}
```

Comment: But I have many columns in array like date, time all are as string is it possible to use only few columns for `uksort`

Comment: that's what i have done. I only check the first three elements of the key. I also added casting so the second is compared as an integer and the third as a float.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the output you are showing, you can use the `ksort()` function -http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.ksort.php.

```
<?php
$test = array(
"462 1 5.300" => 1,
"462 9 4.900" => 1,
"462 9 4.300" => 1,
"462 2 4.800" => 1,
"462 6 4.700" => 1,
"462 7 4.900" => 1,
"462 7 4.700" => 1,
"462 8 4.500" => 1,
"462 3 4.500" => 1,
"462 4 4.700" => 1,
"462 3 4.700" => 1,
"462 5 4.500" => 1
);

print_r($test);
ksort($test);
print_r($test);
?>
```